# Convert PSD and EPS to PNG or JPG using GraphicsMagick for node.js in AWS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am developing a DAM which is hosted in AWS. The user is able to upload heavy files to the system. Under the hood, when an image is uploaded, there is an AWS Lambda function creating a thumbnail for each image.

Obviously files with format .psd and .eps cannot be displayed on the browser with the typical HTML img item. That is why I will need to convert those file formats to .png or .jpg.

Maybe another solution would be to take a "screenshot on the fly" directly in .png. I do not know if this is possible.

The Node.js code running on the Lambda function is very similar the one here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser-create-test-function-create-function.html

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: What application generates `.PDS` files?

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake. I have edited the answer. Thanks Mark for pointing it out.

Comment: What is your actual question? You seem to have a template and to know the tool you want to use - so what is your stumbling block?

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks for trying to help me out. My stumbling block point is that I do not know how I can create a thumbnail on the fly with .png format when the files uploaded are .psd and .eps. These files could be 200MB and I need a thumbnail version which could be used as a preview in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know much about AWS, Lambda and Node.js but can maybe help somewhat with the ImageMagick aspects...

To convert an image from one format to another with ImageMagick, you basically use the `convert` program with appropriate filename extensions like this in the Terminal, or at the command-line:

```
convert input.jpg output.png     # convert a JPEG to a PNG
```

**EPS files**

With `EPS`, which is a vector format, you generally should set the density first, else ImageMagick will use 72 dpi which makes for horrible quality, so for `EPS` try something like:

```
convert -density 144 input.eps output.png
```

**PSD files**

With Photoshop `PSD` files, there is generally a preview image and all the multiple layers following afterwards, so, if you are looking to get a Preview, you should use this style of command to address the layer 0 preview in the PSD file:

```
convert input.psd[0] output.png
```

If you want to reduce the size of an image, you would resize it after loading like this:

```
convert input.png -resize 512x256 output.png
```

to make it no larger than 512 pixels wide or 256 pixels tall.

Another thing you may like to do is to strip the metadata (time/date, camera model, creating application, GPS position of camera) out of the images, for that, add in `-strip` just before the output filename.

Not sure what else I can help with, but hope that gets you started.